# HTTPContext vs HttpModule vs HttpHeader

Tags: browser

Can anyone help me in understanding the below  concepts simple way,
I got this question in one of the interviews,

HTTPContext vs HttpModule vs HttpHeader

Comment: It is best to look up those terms in the internet. This way will get your answers faster.

Comment: I was looking for a crisper definition where in net its like 2 page article which goes no where

Comment: In ASP.Net MVC, HttpContext is the object that contains the information about the page request that can be used in the controller in the form of an object so it can be utilized programmatically, ie if it was a post or a get, form collections. HttpModule is a code block that runs on every request. It is part of the http pipeline i.e. authentication, authorization. HttpHeaders are information in the form of value pairs that comes from your browser during page requests that is sent to the http server. HttpHeader becomes part of HttpContext.

Comment: Thanks  @KristianneNerona Which is the top most parent in this HttpContext vs HttpModule

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. HttpContext is an object and HttpModule is a block of code. Now that you have a gist of what the three are, it is best that you go to the internet and do a web search and get a clearer picture of how they fit in a http request life cycle.

Comment: Here is a clearer picture for your: When you open a webpage or click a submit button, the browser will send the http request containing the http header to the web server. The web server will fire up http modules to check if there is something that needs to be done before the http request object gets processed by the controller, one of which is to convert it into an http context object. This http context object is now passed to your controller or your back end code, in which you may do something or ignore it.